# Does clockwise rotation correspond to a positive or to a negative yaw angle?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I rotate my robot clockwise, should the yaw be increasing or decreasing? I noticed it turns the opposite direction when running slam_mapping in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11142/does-clockwise-rotation-correspond-to-a-positive-or-to-a-negative-yaw-angle?/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) for coordinate system conventions. In general, most coordinate frames follow those conventions, unless otherwise specified.

The short answer is that counter-clockwise is positive change in yaw in a frame that follows REP103 conventions.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexisTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29858/alexistm/) on 2019-03-25**:
"By the right hand rule, the yaw component of orientation increases as the child frame rotates counter-clockwise"

**Comment by [juan.suero.robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/85710/juan.suero.robotics/) on 2022-06-12**:
Alexis yeah but if im looking at the green Y axis headed toward me counterclockwise is one way and if i stand behind the coordinate frame  and look at the y axis going off in the distance counterclockwise is a nother way.

Put another way if i use the right hand rule, and the middle finger is the Y axis then i can point down
but that doesnt tell me clockwise or counter clockwise because from one side of my hand a yaw pointing down its moving counterclockwise and if i look from behind my palm its moving clockwise

in rviz if i place a unit circle  against the 2D frame of the X and Z where X is headed off to the right.. then positive change in radians should be counterclowise but that is not the case.

**Comment by [AlexisTM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29858/alexistm/) on 2022-06-12**:
From X to Y is positive. Meaning with ENU, looking from the top of earth (aka not from the ground), East to North is positive thus CCW is positive.

(Thus for NED, it is the opposite)